# Eclipse RCP cheat sheet for extension points?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, rcp

I do Eclipse RCP plug-ins from time to time. My biggest hurdle is to wrap my head around the extension points (not what they are, but which one to use when). Is there a site where I can find a list like "If you want to **action** extend the following **extension points**.

Such a cheat sheet would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help pages "[**Platform Plug-in Developer Guide > Reference > Extension Points Reference.**](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/index.html) " can be a starting point, in that it helps listing all the categories of extension points.
(mentioned in "[FAQ How do I find out more about a certain extension point?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_find_out_more_about_a_certain_extension_point?)")

If you couple that with the **[plugin spy](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCodeAccess/ar01s03.html)**, you can quickly isolate the right available plugin elements for you to extend.

Comment: That's exactly my problem: I can go through all the extension points and draw conclusions. It is like using a dictionary to learn a language. A dictionary is useful when you know what to look for, but not when you don't know the question.

Comment: @stwissel: quite true, I'll keep looking then.

Answer (score 1):

Some are - also some none Lotus Expeditor - are described with examples in the RedWiki for plugin development. Could be a good start. The wiki is here >> http://bit.ly/pluginredwiki